# Did Skylab have several giant spirit levels? That's what these look like to me, except there's no bubble

Tags: history, identify-this-object, space-station, equipment, skylab

The BBC's [Skylab: The myth of the mutiny in space](https://www.bbc.com/news/stories-56346001) shows the image below of one big circular end bulkhead of the main Skylab main space, with an astronaut in the center hatch and giant air manifolds and other things attached to it.

I see four cylindrical devices that look like they are roughly 12 cm in diameter and 70 cn long. They have what looks like metal caps at each end and about half of the length is metal and the other half appears to me to be transparent (e.g. a glass or plastic tube) because it show almost the same color as the surface behind it, *except brighter.* That increased brightness and possibly other visual cues make me feel as though the transparent section is filled with a liquid.

The transparent section is divided into four sections with what looks like three black lines drawn at the "25%, 50% and 75%" points.

The whole structure looks to me a lot like a giant [spirit level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_level).

**Question:** Did Skylab have several giant spirit levels? That's what these look like to me, except there's no bubble.

---

[image]

**above:** detail from the full image, cropped and rotated, **below** example of a spirit level. [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DetalleNivelDeBurbuja.jpg)

[image]

[image: Skylab: The myth of the mutiny in space]

Answer (score 5):

These are lights: I think they are fluorescent tubes with protective covers (you probably don't want them to break...).

It's hard to find really good information.  However [Skylab: A Guidebook (EP-107)](https://history.nasa.gov/EP-107/contents.htm) contains a number of photographs which convinced me, at least.  And then I eventually found this image:

[image: A mannequin in the Skylab 1-G Trainer at Manned Space Center, Houston]

This comes from the [Wikipedia page on Skylab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab) so it's not a NASA source, but I think it's reasonably compelling.  If I'm right it should be possible to actually go and see the simulator at the MSC to check.

There is further confirmation in [MSFC Skylab Orbital Workshop, volume II](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19740020216/downloads/19740020216.pdf) (warning: large PDF file of a scanned document), which comes directly from NASA.  On page 203 (marked '2.2.7-7') of this document there is a picture of one of these lights, and there is a lot of information on them on this page and pages around it.  Thanks to Organic Marble for this.

---

On the other hand, if *I* got to build spacecraft they would most certainly have spirit levels, as well as rather expensive and ornate wooden panelling and <s>sea</s>space chests for the crew.  Perhaps this is why my proposals keep getting turned down.

Comment: Wow, so the tubes look like they are backed with reflectors, just the opposite of being transparent as I'd thought. As for the interior design, would the navigator's station look a little bit like [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/60711/14213)?

Comment: also, looking at the lighting of the two photographs, it seems that the one in your answer has "ambient lighting" in other words the scene is lit by those fluorescent lamps and probably more around the station. Whereas the one in the question is lit by either a super-powerful flash or a bright spotlight. The fluorescent tubes may be turned on, but based on the shadow there's one really big bright light a little bit "below" the camera position.

Comment: @uhoh: yes your photo looks like a canonical flash photo, where the flash has killed all the ambient light.  Besed on the shadow I bet it's 'upside down' (ie the person taking it was rotated by 180 degrees-ish to the other person).  In my spaceships there would be more teak.  Also I can't see any speaking tubes in that photo.  Otherwise good.

Comment: @uhoh in case it's not clear, the photo in this answer is of the Skylab mockup in Houston (currently at the Space Center Houston museum).  That should explain some of the lighting oddities.

Comment: The rotating guy on a stick gives it away :) This was once the Skylab simulator; moving it from Bldg 5 to SCH was a massive effort.

Comment: Captain Nemo (if not the entire League of Extraordinary Gentlemen) would approve of your decorating choices.

Comment: You can read an unbelievably detailed description of the lighting system in *MSFC Skylab Orbital Workshop Volume 2* https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19740020216/downloads/19740020216.pdf - 42 pages worth.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: thank you.  I will add this.